# My selection listener doesn't seem to be registering properly

Tags: eclipse-rcp, selection

I am creating an Eclipse RCP application with multiple views. One of my views is a multi-page editor view. Each of those pages has a a master/details block. I need to register all of those TableViewers as selection providers for my other view to listen to.

After much research online, I came across [this article](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html) about multiple selection providers in a single view. I followed the instructions to create this selection provider for multiple viewers.

```java
class MyMultipleSelectionProvider implements ISelectionProvider {

private final ListenerList selectionListeners = new ListenerList();

private ISelectionProvider delegate;

private final ISelectionChangedListener selectionListener = new ISelectionChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        if (event.getSelectionProvider() == AdaptabilityProfileSelectionProvider.this.delegate) {
            fireSelectionChanged( event.getSelection() );
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Sets a new selection provider to delegate to. Selection listeners
 * registered with the previous delegate are removed before. 
 * 
 * @param newDelegate new selection provider
 */
public void setSelectionProviderDelegate(final ISelectionProvider newDelegate) {
    if (this.delegate == newDelegate) {
        return;
    }
    if (this.delegate != null) {
        this.delegate.removeSelectionChangedListener(this.selectionListener);
    }
    this.delegate = newDelegate;
    if (newDelegate != null) {
        newDelegate.addSelectionChangedListener(this.selectionListener);
        fireSelectionChanged(newDelegate.getSelection());
    }
}


@Override
public void addSelectionChangedListener(final ISelectionChangedListener listener) {
    this.selectionListeners.add(listener);
}

@Override
public ISelection getSelection() {
    return this.delegate == null ? null : this.delegate.getSelection();
}

@Override
public void removeSelectionChangedListener(final ISelectionChangedListener listener) {
    this.selectionListeners.remove(listener);
}

@Override
public void setSelection(final ISelection selection) {
    if (this.delegate != null) {
        this.delegate.setSelection(selection);
    }
}
protected void fireSelectionChanged(final ISelection selection) {
    fireSelectionChanged(this.selectionListeners, selection);
}

private void fireSelectionChanged(final ListenerList list, final ISelection selection) {
    final SelectionChangedEvent event = new SelectionChangedEvent(this.delegate, selection);

    final Object[] listeners = list.getListeners();
    for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
        final ISelectionChangedListener listener = (ISelectionChangedListener) listeners[i];
        listener.selectionChanged(event);
    }
}
}
```

I added a focusListener on all of the edior's viewers so they become the delegate:

```java
    tree.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(final FocusEvent e) {
            editor.getSelectionProvider().setSelectionProviderDelegate(MyEditorPage.this.treeViewer);
        }
    });
```

And I registered this as the selection provider for my editor:

```java
site.setSelectionProvider( this.selectionProvider  );
```

Then, within my view that needs to hear about the selection, I registered a selection listener for this editor:

```java
getSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(MyEditor.ID, this.selectionListener);
```

When I run the application, I see that the delegate is being changed and the selection events are being fired. However, the listener list is empty.

I am never calling addSelectionChangeListener() directly. I was under the impression that that was what the selection service is for. Am I wrong? Should I be calling it? If so, when? If not, who is supposed to be adding the listener, and why isn't it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is based on `FormEditor` (or `MultiPageEditorPart`) then the selection provider is set to `MultiPageSelectionProvider` at the end of the `init` method. This may be overriding your `site.setSelectionProvider` call.

Using:

```java
@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)
        throws PartInitException {
    super.init(site, input);

    site.setSelectionProvider(this.selectionProvider);
}
```

should make sure your provider is the one used.